# Globaly fetch python class variable

Tags: python

```
Class Information:
   def __init__(self):
      self.name = 200

   def ajust(self):
      self.name = 250


Class Jesus:
   def __init__(self):
      self.age = 10

   def ajust(self):
      self.age = 20

Printdata = Information()
print(Printdata.name)

________________________
Result: >>> 200
```

This print is printing out the first name value. how can i get it to print the value after calling `ajust`? i want it to print 250, not 200. i have looked all over stackoverflow to find a solution. Keep in mind this is not my actual code, just a simple example to showcase my issue.

Comment: You have to call the `.adjust()` method to update the value `name`

Comment: `Information()` will result in calling the `__init__` of `Information` for a new instance `self`.  The code inside `ajust` has no effect until you call it

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `ajust()` first

```
Printdata = Information()
Printdata.ajust()
print(Printdata.name)
```

However once you call it `name` will always be 250, I suggest you use `property` instead to allow more changes

```
class Information:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = 200

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = value


information = Information()
print(information.name) # 200
information.name = 250
print(information.name) # 250
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at what's going on here behind the scenes.
Your class information has a **constructor**(in python these are defined by the method __init__(self).

When you call Information(), in reality you are calling the constructor, which returns an instance of your object, in this case an Information object, it also sets name to 200.

So when you print name on a newly built Information, name will be 200.

You have an ajust method. But you'll need to call it in order to update the name variable inside the class.

So your order of events should be: Build the class, call ajust, print name